# Running inlined webworker code from within typescript project

Tags: typescript, web-worker

I am developing browser code using Typescript. Some of my code I want to run in a web worker.

Other than writing separate script files, what I would like to achieve is to have a class which wraps the Webworker and provide a method `run(method: Function, ...args: any[])`. This method I could then pass a function together with the argument values to call the function with in the worker. I can make this work using the `Blob` object as explained here https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/#toc-inlineworkers

The problem I run into though, is that the function I pass to `run` could have calls to `postMessage` in its body, which is the `postMessage` of the web worker global scope, not the DOM global scope. Hence, Typescript complains, because both have a incompatible declaration.

Does anybody have a suggestion how this could possibly work?

### Option 1

Cast `postMessage` inside the function body as

```
`(postMessage as any)('Hi from web worker')
```

but that is ugly.

### Option 2

would be to turn this `lib.dom.d.ts` signature

```
declare function postMessage(message: any, targetOrigin: string, transfer?: any[]): void;
```

into

```
declare function postMessage(message: any, targetOrigin?: string, transfer?: any[]): void;
```

(see the question mark added)

But is there something better?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem. Here are my options:

## Option 3

```js
// @ts-ignore
postMessage(result);
```

## Option 4

```js
const postMessageOnWorker = postMessage as (message: any) => void;
postMessageOnWorker(result);
```

When I put the second argument like `postMessage(result, "*")`, it caused runtime-error (at least on Chrome). So, the second argument is not optional, it shouldn't be there.